# How do I share labels across collections in matplotlib? Or how do I produce the legend cleanly?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use matplotlib to show some data in a clear way. My current goal is to label the data using two methods: color and shape. The color will be used to represent the data set these specific points come from, while the shape is used to represent whether that example is in category one or two. To visualize this, here is a simple example I drew in PowerPoint:

[image: Sample Plot]

The reason for doing this instead of simply creating a legend with each specific data set and category stated is I am plotting upwards of 10 data sets, so the legend would remain significantly cleaner and easier to read if color was used for the data sets and shape used for general category (thus the legend would show 10 colors and two shapes, as opposed to 20 different color-shape combinations).

I am currently able to use matplotlib to set the label of the individual data sets by iterating through them and plotting each individually as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.figure()
for data in datasets:
    scat_plot = ax.scatter(data[x], data[y], label=data[label])
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

However, when I attempt to plot the individual shapes and colors and assign them the same label, I am left with plots that do not recognize the two scatter collections as having the same label.

Any suggestions or hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The docs have some pretty relevant examples.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html

Comment: Thanks! I also found some useful information on [link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) under the section **Legend Handlers**.